# How to Show Menu after full size window in responsive Design

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a responsive site. in my site I dont use anything css framework.
in desktop view when resize browser to mobile and table ,work very well,but after maximum window to desktop view it is'nt show menu,its hide?
how can I fix it?

Comment: You should share some code with us! Screenshots and/or a jsfiddle are very helpful too. We can't guess what's going on on your page. Do you use media queries?

Comment: yes , I use media query . I think must after maximum window, check by jquery if menu is hide chande its to show .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can force the menu to show up by adding important next to the css value, it's something like this:

```
@media screen and (min-width:990px){
  .menu{ display: block!important }
}
```

Comment: Personally, I don't like to use `!important` but I know that there are a few cases where you have to use it. With media queries it is often sufficient to check the order of the style definitions.

Comment: @lupz you're right, the important argument should not be used often, but as you said, there is some case where you need to use it, like when there is an inline style generated by javascript.

Comment: That's the reason, why I don't like to set styles directly from js. I prefer to add/remove class memberships. But I consider this off-topic :)